# How can I access all the "text" properties of the json of cucumber's "step"-object and log them to the console?

Tags: javascript, json, webdriver-io, cucumberjs, wdio-v6

I'm trying to log the string/regex of a step description of a cucumber 'step'-oject to the console. This is an example step

```
Given Alice is hungry
```

... and this is the first line to the step definition

```
Given( /^Alice is hungry$/, () => {
```

I'm trying to log 'Given Alice is hungry' to console, using the string representation of a 'step'-object that's provided as an argument, in the context of a cucumber-specific hook of webdriverio. Running

```
beforeStep: function ({ uri, feature, step }, context) {
    console.log(`Running "${JSON.stringify(step, null, 4)}"`);
}
```

...produces this output:

```
[0-0] Running "{
    "uri": "featureFiles\\dev\\my-first-feature-file.feature",
    "feature": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "tags": [],
        "location": {
            "line": 8,
            "column": 1
        },
        "language": "en",
        "keyword": "Functionality",
        "name": "Eating too many cucumbers is not good for you",
        "children": [
            {
                "type": "Scenario",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "type": "Tag",
                        "location": {
                            "line": 10,
                            "column": 3
                        },
                        "name": "@Szenario-Eating-all-the-cucumbers"
                    }
                ],
                "location": {
                    "line": 11,
                    "column": 3
                },
                "keyword": "Szenario",
                "name": "Eating a few is no problem",
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "type": "Hook",
                        "location": {
                            "line": 187,
                            "column": 0,
                            "uri": "node_modules\\@wdio\\cucumber-framework\\build\\index
.js"
                        },
                        "keyword": "Hook",
                        "text": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Step",
                        "location": {
                            "line": 12,
                            "column": 3
                        },
                        "keyword": "Given",
                        "text": "Alice is hungry"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Step",
                        "location": {
                            "line": 13,
                            "column": 5
                        },
                        "keyword": "When ",
                        "text": "she eats 3 cucumbers'"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Step",
                        "location": {
                            "line": 14,
                            "column": 5
                        },
                        "keyword": "Then ",
                        "text": "she will be full"
                    },
```

However, when I use

```js
beforeStep: function ({ uri, feature, step }, context) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    console.log(\`Running step "${step.text}"`);
}
```

...all i get is

```
 [0-0] Running "undefined"
 [0-0] Running "undefined"
```

I've tried these 2 options instead:

```
console.log(`Running "${step.feature.children.steps.text}"`);
console.log(`Running "${feature.children.steps.text}"`);
```

In both cases this produces the following result:

```
[0-0] Error in "BeforeStep Hook"
Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see a text under step directly. It looks like text is under step.children.steps. you may need to use to get all the text values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this example:

```
${step.feature.children.steps.text}
```

`children` is an array, so you can't just type `.steps`. You need to access a certain element first, like `[0].steps`.

Similarly with steps, steps is an array:

```json
"steps": [ ... ]
```

This `${step.text}` doesn't work because `step` doesn't have a property text. It has the following keys:

```
uri
feature
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted **pavelsman** answer as the problem's solution.

For anyone who wants to log the cucumber steps to the console right when they're executing, just add this to the wdio-configuration file:

```
let scenarioIndex = 0;
let stepIndex = 0;

beforeStep: function ({uri, feature, step}, context) {
    if(typeof step.feature.children[scenarioIndex] !== "undefined") {
        let keyword = step.feature.children[scenarioIndex].steps[stepIndex].keyword;
        let stepText = step.feature.children[scenarioIndex].steps[stepIndex].text;
        if (stepText !== "") {
            console.log(keyword + stepText);
        }
        stepIndex++;
    }
},
afterScenario: function () {
    scenarioIndex++;
    stepIndex = 0;
},
```